# Trying to align text sending mail using php mail function

Tags: php, email, alignment

i am sending some HTML text using the PHP mail function.

So the text is

```
$msg='<h1>This is the mail text i want to center</h1>';
```

then i am using the mail function like:

```
mail($recipient,$subject,$msg,$mailheaders);
```

I receive the email but all text is left aligned.
I tried to use center tags

```
$msg='<center><h1>This is the mail text i want to center</h1></center>';
```

but the mail never goes (it is not allowed?)

also tried to use style attribute

```
$msg='<h1 style="text-align:center;">This is the mail text i want to center</h1>';
```

but again no luck. 
Any ideas welcome

Comment: You need to specify that it's html in the headers sent. Also you'd be better off using a third party library like phpmailer to handle this.

Comment: @Akintunde "You need to specify that it's html in the headers sent" how should i do this?

Comment: Show the $mailheaders variable

Answer (score 1):

it's always hard to send a good mail with a nice design.

One (old) way is to use table but it's not really nice. Now you can use some good third party libs like phpmailer or others. 
You will need to apply inline css since providers don't supports external CSS.

check this article https://www.formget.com/php-send-html-email-template/

Comment: I have managed to style the mail enough using mail function but i'm missing some basic php properties. I will try the article though